# Java Http upload instant speed / progress

Tags: java, http

I would like to compute accurate instant http upload speed in java to be able to draw a graph of speed over time. I am currently using HttpUrlConnection and fixed length mode.

The problem is that doing something like the following is wrong:

```
for (;;) {
    startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    OutputStream.write(volume)   
    endTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    instantSpeed = volume / (endTime - startTime); 
}
```

Because the data is not necessarly sent during the OutputStream.write() call. I only know that everything is sent once the HttpUrlConnection.getResponseCode method returns.

Does anyone have a solution to compute the instant upload http speed ?